# Is it technically correct to pass around a struct of pointers in modern C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a C++ program that uses Qt for logic and GUI. As program evolve I find that there is a lot of pointer communication that is needed especially for GUI. I'm thinking of having a C++ structure that holds a pointer to all Objects that are needed to passed around so that any other object in need of another object could draw from this structure of pointers.

```
struct ObjectPointers {
    FirstObject *firstObject = shared_ptr firstClass;
    SecondObject *secondObject = shared_ptr secondClass;
    ThirdObject *thirdOjbect = shared_ptr secondClass;
    ...
}
```

Any other object in need of one of the object would do the following;

```
// Initializing the ObjectPointers instance
ObjectPointers *ops = shared_ptr ObjectPointers;

// Initializing some random object instance
SomeNewOjbect sno{ops->secondObject};
```

Is this approach technically acceptable? Is it overkill? Are there corner cases that I might have overlooked? What is the alternative?

Comment: Structures are classes in C++. There are also POD objects. It is a bit unclear what the problem is. Maybe you should try this over at [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Avoid cross posting.

Comment: `structure ObjectPointers {FirstObject *firstObject = shared_ptr firstClass;` syntax seems to be invalid. Is this really C++? Use of `shared_ptr` everywhere is an overkill, it should only be used to shared ownership in complex scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused as to how shared_ptr works, and what its for. Possibly due to trying to impose Java/C# semantics onto your C++ program.

I'm assuming that your `FirstObject` `SecondObject` etc are all long lived things managed elsewhere, like top level windows and their data-structures.

> ```
> struct ObjectPointers {
>     FirstObject *firstObject = shared_ptr firstClass;
>     SecondObject *secondObject = shared_ptr secondClass;
>     ThirdObject *thirdOjbect = shared_ptr secondClass;
>     ...
> }
> ```

Firstly this isn't c++ syntax. Is `shared_ptr firstClass` meant to have some `<>`? `FirstObject * firstObject` is a (raw) pointer to a thing of type `FirstObject` which would normally be entirely unrelated to `firstClass` instances.

This reads like default initialzing a shared_ptr and then assigning it to a raw pointer, which is also invalid, unless your (non-standard) shared_ptr provides a default conversion to raw pointer. The net effect of that is the same as assigning `nullptr` in those locations.

To answer your question, having such a struct (having a bunch of "pointy" members) isn't per-se bad, but indicates an architecture that could be reworked such that as few things as possible are needed in any one place. The specifics of using shared_ptr is also questionable, as it implies you don't know the lifetime of these objects.

```
struct MyObjects {
    MyObjects() : 
      firstObject(/* get firstObject from somewhere */),  
      secondObject(/* get secondObject from elsewhere */),
      ...
      {}
    FirstObject & firstObject;
    SecondObject & secondObject;
    ...
}
```

This would be used when I know that `MyObjects` is used entirely within `firstObject`, `secondObject`, etc's lifetimes, passed around as neccecary